# Roma pass vs. Colosseum/Forum tickets?

Tags: tickets, italy, museums, rome

Going to Rome with girlfriend in a couple of weeks, and finalizing last minute details.

I am confused about ticketing.

When buying a ticket for the Colosseum, we can also get into the Roman Forum/Palatine hill within 2 consecutive days.

If I look at the Roma Pass; it says that I can have "free" access to 2 museums in 3 days (as well as other goodies)

Does that include both the Colosseum and Forum/Palatine AND another museum during the 3 days? 
Do I have to do the Colosseum and Forum/Palatine within 2 consecutive days and a second museum within the 3 consecutive days ?

We plan to do the Colosseum (not that long a visit AFAIRemember) one morning, the Palatine Hill/Forum another morning and the "second" museum the third day. (all depending on the weather).

Edit:

We finally only visited the Forum and Palatine hills; we skipped the Colosseum this time.

We used the Roma pass for a couple of other exhibits/museums.

Thanks.

Comment: The official tour guides can get you queue-jump tickets, explain a lot, take you to most of the places you want to see, and aren't very much more than just booking tickets alone for the group tours. You might want to consider that

Comment: @Gagravarr Make sure you book official tour guides and not the unlicenced ones that make stuff up such as the column of snow falling through the hole on the roof of the Pantheon.

Comment: Note that there are two queues at Coloseum, one for buying tickets, second one after that to enter the building. The queue-jump tickets allow only to jump first queue. Everybody has to queue in second, & on 26th April this year, it was 4+ hours at 10am..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can visit both the Colosseum and Forum/Palatine AND another museum during the three days.

Source: [On the RomaPass list of Museums](http://www.romapass.it/p.aspx?l=en&tid=37) the "Colosseo/ Palatino/Foro Romano" is listed as one attraction/museum and it even explicitly states: "CUMULATIVE TICKET: (Anfiteatro Flavio) Colosseo + Palatino + Foro Romano."